# FFMPEG Concat filter - Output video skips second file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, concatenation

I am using the ffmpeg concat filter to join video files. I am aware the files must be exactly the same format for concat to work without encoding. However, the output of these two files are not seemless. The video will stop when it switches to second video file.

Here is the output of the two video files.

```
SKYbum:~ Aspvik$ ffmpeg -i /Users/Aspvik/Desktop/newIntro.mp4 -i /Users/Aspvik/Downloads/wetransfer-008789/Middle.mp4 
ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/Aspvik/Desktop/newIntro.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.87, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7160 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 7159 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/Aspvik/Downloads/wetransfer-008789/Middle.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Netcam Studio 1.6.1.0
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:19.47, start: 0.033008, bitrate: 676 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 674 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

The command I'm using for the concat is:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i /Users/Aspvik/Desktop/files.txt -codec copy -y /Users/Aspvik/Desktop/video.mp4
```

Can anyone see what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you share the files?

Comment: "File 2" is being recorded in that format and has to stay that way, however "file 1" I can encode.
File 1: https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/vmh/bf7333d0964cf273d6feeb4084a63ae34dee2e7867c9c58114e3d0e0f71d790b.mp4

File 2: https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/vmh/0001515db48bee5eab35fca542e384a4527da81e1bb608d58f0cefacce670969.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=A7AG6AVBHTRQ7EBMJK67%2F20181016%2Fams3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20181016T062327Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=f82036961dabe8b7636ecf40f2d3d743684527dea94e783c8a34a5573c1562b9